# How would I test for a certain digit in a variable?

Tags: javascript, digits

Lets say I had a variable called `test` and `test = 123456789;`. Then I have another variable called `anotherTest` and `anotherTest = 1234;`. How would I make a program that can test whether a variable has the digit 5 or not? Then, how could it sort the variables into two groups of which one group of variables has the digit "5" within it and the other without? Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: 'sort the variables into two groups' based on what? Given the string `123456789` what should each of the two groups contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I make a program that can test whether a variable has the digit 5 or not?

You can readily do that with strings and `indexOf`:

```
if (String(test).indexOf("5") !== -1) {
    // It has a 5 in it
}
```

> Then, how could it sort the variables into two groups of which one group of variables has the digit "5" within it and the other without?

You can't sort the *variables* into groups, but you can certainly sort *values* into groups. For example, this loops through an array and adds values to either the `with5` or `without5` array depending on whether the value contains the digit `5`:

```js
var a = [
  1234,
  12345,
  123123,
  555555
];
var with5 = [];
var without5 = [];
a.forEach(function(value) {
  if (String(value).indexOf("5") === -1) {
    without5.push(value);
  } else {
    with5.push(value);
  }
});
snippet.log("with5: " + with5.join(", "));
snippet.log("without5: " + without5.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

The above assumes base 10 (decimal) strings, but you can easily do the same with hexadecimal or octal or any other base you like by using `Number#toString(base)`. E.g.:

```
var s = num.toString(16);
```

...will assign `s` the value of `num` as a hexadecimal (base 16) string.

Answer (score 0):

To see if a number contains the digit "5", you can just convert the numbers to strings and then just use `.indexOf("5")` on each string.

```
var test = 123456789;
var anotherTest = 1234;

// reports whether the passed in number or string contains the
// character "5"
function containsDigit5(val) {
    // convert number to string
    // if already string, then it is left as is
    val = "" + val;
    return val.indexOf("5") >= 0;
}

containsDigit5(test);           // true
containsDigit5(anotherTest);    // false
```

The grouping part of your question is not entirely clear, but you can just call this function on each variable and add the numbers to one of two arrays.

```
var testNumbers = [123456789, 1234];
var has5 = [];
var doesNotHave5 = [];

// reports whether the passed in number or string contains the
// character "5"
function containsDigit5(val) {
    // convert number to string
    // if already string, then it is left as is
    val = "" + val;
    return val.indexOf("5") >= 0;
}

testNumbers.forEach(function(item) {
    if (containsDigit5(item)) {
        has5.push(testNumbers[i]);
    } else {
        doesNotHave5.push(testNumbers[i]);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating with an empty string, you can also use the `toFixed()` method, which might be a bit easier to read. (But I didn't do the downvote)

Comment: @sqykly - what's wrong with the code?  Downvotes should explain why so the answer can be improved.  The point here is to get the best answers.

Comment: @YMMD - yes `.toFixed()` might work also, but it's not clear why it is needed here.  Adding to an empty string is a classic way of making sure a number is converted to a string.  It has the added benefit that if the value is already a string, it will still work, but `.toFixed()` does not have that benefit.

Comment: Odd, there are two downvoters here with ZERO explanation.  Downvoters please explain.  Questions can be improved based on feedback, but an unexplained downvote does not generate any improvement just mystery.

Comment: @YMMD - FYI, in [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-conversion-perf), you can see that `"" + val` is more than 100x faster than `val.toFixed(20)` and 6x faster than `String(val)` as measured in Chrome.  The performance advantage of `""+ val` is even larger in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each character of variable test, then compare using indexOf() to see if it exists in anotherTest. If so add to one array, otherwise add to array 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RegExp, or `.indexOf`. Either works:

---

## RegEx

Everyone hates RegExp for some reason, but I like it. You can use:

```
var test = 123456789,
    anotherTest = 1234;

/5/.test(test);
/5/.test(anotherTest);
```

```js
var test = 123456789,
    anotherTest = 1234;

document.write( 'test (123456789): ' + /5/.test(test) + '<br/>' );
document.write( 'anotherTest (1234): ' + /5/.test(anotherTest) );
```

---

## indexOf

This can be faster in some situations, but not always, it is also a bit more "complicated", at least in my opinion:

```
var test = 123456789,
    anotherTest = 1234;

(test+'').indexOf(5) > -1;
(anotherTest+'').indexOf(5) > -1;
```

```js
var test = 123456789,
    anotherTest = 1234;

document.write( 'test (123456789): ' + ((test+'').indexOf(5) > -1) + '<br/>' );
document.write( 'anotherTest (1234): ' + ((anotherTest+'').indexOf(5) > -1) + '<br/>' );
```

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right, I was answering this quickly and messed that up :P